# joining an azure static web app on one repository with the API on another repository

Tags: azure-api-apps, azure-static-web-app

I built a static web app and the html page is on one of my respositories.  I built the API and it is on another repository.  How do I link the two? Can I link the two?  Or should I build a new static web app in the API repository?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can link an existing Azure Functions app to an Azure Static Web Apps resource using 'Bring your own functions to Azure Static Web Apps'.

Example

Consider an existing Azure Functions app that exposes an endpoint via the following location.

https://my-functions-app.azurewebsites.net/api/getProducts

Once linked, you can access that same endpoint through the api path from your static web app, as shown in this example URL.

https://red-sea-123.azurestaticapps.net/api/getProducts

Both endpoint URLs point to the same function.

**Link an existing Azure Functions app**

Before you associate an existing Functions app, you first need to adjust to configuration of your static web app.

1. Set api_location value to an empty string ("") in the workflow
   configuration file.
2. Open your Static Web Apps instance in the Azure portal.
3. From the Settings menu, select Functions.
4. From the Environment dropdown, select Production.
5. Next to the Functions source label, select Link to a Function app.
6. From the Subscription dropdown, select your Azure subscription name.
7. From the Function App dropdown, select the name of the existing
   Functions app you want to link to your static web app.
8. Select the Link button.

**Deployment**
You're responsible for setting up a deployment workflow for your Azure Functions app.

See steps and more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/static-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own)